# Detect Shift key + click event on iCheck checkbox

Tags: javascript, checkbox, icheck

My web page uses `iCheck` checkboxes. I am trying to get event when `Shift` key is pressed along with clicking on checkboxes. but no where in the documentation, `iCheck` gives that notification like normal `document.click(function())` gives.

I am using

```
$('input[name=selectinp]').on('ifChanged', function(event){ 
...
});
```

Here, **event.shiftkey** is undefined.
Please help.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but I will answer it to help any future folks that are looking for solutions.   The iCheck library does not pass through the entire click event, so you can't check for `event.shiftKey`.  Instead, you have to manually build your own variable that stores whether the shift key is pressed or not:

```
var shiftIsPressed = false;
$(window).keydown(keyDownHandler);
$(window).keyup(keyUpHandler);

function keyDownHandler(event) {
  if (event.key == "Shift") {
    shiftIsPressed = true;
  }
}

function keyUpHandler(event) {
  if (event.key == "Shift") {
    shiftIsPressed = false;
  }
}

$('input[name=selectinp]').on('ifChanged', function(event){ 
  if (shiftIsPressed) {
    ...
  } else {
    ...
  }
});
```